# Calling, and awaiting, an F# async method, from C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#

I have this in F#:

```
type RuleStore() =

    ...
    static member LoadAsync : Async<RulesStore> =
        async {
            let! r = Startup.States.GetAsStringAsync("rules") |> Async.AwaitTask

            return
                if String.IsNullOrEmpty r then
                    new RulesStore()
                else
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RulesStore>(r);
        }
```

and I am trying to call it from C#, but the syntax doesn't seem to work.

> NewRules = await Rules.RulesStore.LoadAsync();

The error I get is:

> Core.cs(29, 38): [CS1955] Non-invocable member 'Rules.RulesStore.LoadAsync' cannot be used like a method.

which I don't quite understand because I'm under the impression that LoadAsync is just a static method.

Comment: As long as both compile into CIL, their source langauge does not mater. Only the CIL features they were compiled with does. | The error message also clearly states that you are using something that is interpreted to be a field, property, event or other "not a function" like a Function.

Comment: that's the part I do not understand. why isn't a static member of a type a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons why you can't call `await Rules.RulesStore.LoadAsync()`.

First, your code is actually defining a get-only property. In F#, the syntax for defining a get-only property is quite similar to the syntax for defining methods:

```
static member LoadAsync : Async<RulesStore> =   // Defines a get-only property
static member LoadAsync() : Async<RulesStore> = // Defines a method
```

You could go with a get-only property and call `await Rules.RulesStore.LoadAsync`, but that would probably seem odd to C# callers, so method seems a better option.

Second, your code is returning `Async<'T>` but C# works with `Task<'T>` type instead. You could convert Async to Task in C#, but it is easier to do this on the F# side. To do this, you need to change the type and add `Async.StartAsTask` to the end (as a personal stylistic preference, I'd also have `return` inside `if`, but that's just because I think it looks nicer):

```
type RuleStore() =

    ...
    static member LoadAsync : Task<RulesStore> =
        async {
            let! r = Startup.States.GetAsStringAsync("rules") |> Async.AwaitTask
            if String.IsNullOrEmpty r then
                return new RulesStore()
            else
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RulesStore>(r);
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Comment: so, when I do a non static definition, like member this.SaveAsync for example, this would be considered a property?

Comment: Yes, without (), it's a property. Or you could define a property `with get`. There are several ways to do it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties